# Download Yahoo Data into open Excel table

Tags: python, excel, yahoo-api

I want to download data from Yahoo Finance. I know how to download data to the new or closed Excel file. But I want to find a way to **download data** tables into **open Excel file**.
Specifically I have a list of stocks and I want to create a   new worksheet for each stock in a list.

```
import win32com.client
import datetime as dt

ExcelApp = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelWrkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks(1)
ExcelWrksht = ExcelWrkbook.Worksheets(1)

#get stock list
Input_Range = ExcelWrksht.Range("B1:V1")
Input_Stock_Names = []
for cellItm in Input_Range:
    Input_Stock_Names.append(cellItm.value)
number_of_stocks = len(Input_Stock_Names)


#import data from Yahoo
import pandas_datareader as pdr

starting_date = dt.datetime(2020,4,1)
ending_date = dt.datetime.today()

n=number_of_stocks
m = 0
while n > 0:
    x = Input_Stock_Names[m]
    m+=1
    n-=1
    df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(x,starting_date,ending_date)
    df = df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write to an open Excel file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191394/how-to-write-to-an-open-excel-file-using-python)

Comment: What specifically is your question? How to create a new sheet?

Comment: @BigBen I can create a new sheet but I do not know how to paste dataframe content into this new spreadsheet (starting from A1).                                                         `
    `df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(x,starting_date,ending_date)
    df = df.reset_index()
    
    ExcelWrksht = ExcelWrkbook.Worksheets.Add()
    ExcelWrksht.Name = x
    ExcelWrksht = ExcelWrkbook.Worksheets(x)`