# Writing data to Excel spread sheet while open

Tags: python, excel

Currently, I am writing a python script that handles excel data using OpenPYXL. I am trying to create an interface in excel that updates data in the spreadsheet cells in a cyclic way. I understand that I cannot write to an open excel file, as it gives me a permission error. Is there a way to bypass this without having to close the file and run the script every time new data is to appear?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191394/how-to-write-to-an-open-excel-file-using-python

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid no, you must close files before writing.

Comment: ... if you're using openpxyl, then yes. However with other libraries, one can write to an open Excel file.

Comment: @BigBen Such as?

Comment: `xlwings` or `win32com`.