# Need python code to export the output into excel worksheet when excel file is open

Tags: python, excel, loops, export

My code is as follow. When i run below code, the output is shown in pyhton as a table. This output is in loop mode since the data is related to live data.
I need this result table to be exported into an excel file's worksheet "Sheet1" when the excel file is open and keep on updating the live data in excel worksheet every time when the python code runs in loop, until i close the python code file / excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os


def fetch_NSE_stock_price(stock_code):
    stock_url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=' + str(
        stock_code)
    # print(stock_url)
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'}
    response = requests.get(stock_url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    data_array = soup.find(id='responseDiv').getText().strip().split(":")

    for item in data_array:
        if 'lastPrice' in item:
            index = data_array.index(item) + 1
            latestPrice = data_array[index].split('"')[1]
            lp = float(latestPrice.replace(',', ''))
        elif 'closePrice' in item:
            index = data_array.index(item) + 1
            closePrice = data_array[index].split('"')[1]
            cp = float(closePrice.replace(',', ''))
        elif 'open' in item:
            index = data_array.index(item) + 1
            openPrice = data_array[index].split('"')[1]
            op = float(openPrice.replace(',', ''))
        elif 'dayLow' in item:
            index = data_array.index(item) + 1
            dayLow = data_array[index].split('"')[1]
            dl = float(dayLow.replace(',', ''))
        elif 'dayHigh' in item:
            index = data_array.index(item) + 1
            dayHigh = data_array[index].split('"')[1]
            dh = float(dayHigh.replace(',', ''))
    return op, lp, dh, dl, cp


nifty50_url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/content/indices/ind_nifty50list.csv'
df_n50 = pd.read_csv(nifty50_url)

regexp = re.compile('&')

OP = []
LP = []
DHP = []
DLP = []
CP = []

while True:
    try:
        for index, row in df_n50.iterrows():
            stock_code = row['Symbol']
            if (regexp.search(stock_code) != None):
                stock_code = stock_code.replace('&', '%26')

            oPrice, lPrice, dhPrice, dlPrice, cPrice = fetch_NSE_stock_price(stock_code)
            OP.append(str(oPrice))
            LP.append(str(lPrice))
            DHP.append(str(dhPrice))
            DLP.append(str(dlPrice))
            CP.append(str(cPrice))

        os.system('cls')
        print(
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("|{:50s} | {:20s} | {:10s} | {:10s} | {:10s} | {:10s} | {:10s}|".format('Company Name', 'Symbol',
                                                                                      'openPrice', 'lastPrice',
                                                                                      'dayHigh', 'dayLow',
                                                                                      'closePrice'))
        print(
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

        for index, row in df_n50.iterrows():
            stock_code = row['Symbol']

            print("|{:50s} | {:20s} | {:10s} |{:10s} | {:10s} | {:10s} | {:10s} |".format(str(row['Company Name']),
                                                                                          row['Symbol'],
                                                                                          OP[index].rjust(10),
                                                                                          LP[index].rjust(10),
                                                                                          DHP[index].rjust(10),
                                                                                          DLP[index].rjust(10),
                                                                                          CP[index].rjust(10)))

        print(
            "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code. Generally, search for "pywin32 excel" (maybe add "tutorial") to find e. g. https://jpereiran.github.io/articles/2019/06/14/Excel-automation-with-pywin32.html or https://pythonexcels.com/python/2009/10/05/python-excel-mini-cookbook

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191394/how-to-write-to-an-open-excel-file-using-python