# Find Similarity on Excel Column - Brand, Product Name and Weight

Tags: python, machine-learning, sentence-similarity

I'll try to explain you, as far as I can, my new Python Challenge!
We have two datasets in Excell for two different Retailer (supermarket) and in each of them there are some information about their products (name, brand, weight, etc.) but with different structures (see the example table 1-2 below).

| Brand 1 | Name 1 | Weight 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ferrero spa | Nutella | 250g |
| Barilla | Pasta Inegrale | 500g |
| Coca Cola | Zero Sugar | 500ml |

| Brand 2 | Name 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Ferrero | Nutella 250gr |
| Barilla | Pasta Ineg. 500gr |
| Pepsi | Zero Sug. 500gml |

The goal would be an NLP Text Similarity Algorithm able to identify the common products btw the two retailer as accurately as possible.
(To be honest at the moment I can't give you more guidance on the output because I also don't know much about this world of ML)

Thank you very much in advance for the availability and good luck!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you can use an NLP library, such as [spaCy](https://spacy.io/) or [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) to *tekenize* the **product names** and compute their similarity scores. This is done by iterating over all the **products** in both datasets and computing the similarity scores between each pair of products. Additionally, it will be setting a threshold for the similarity score to determine if two products are similar enough to be considered the same. In the end, it will output the list of **common products** between the two datasets.

Therefore, you will need to do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

df1 = pd.read_excel("retailer1.clsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("retailer2.clsx")

def preprocess(text):
  text = text,lower()

  doc = npl(text)
  tokens = [token.text for token in doc if not token.is_stop and token.is_alpha]
  return " ".join(tokens)

df1["Name"] = df1["Name"].apply(preprocess)
df2["Name"] = df2["Name"].apply(preprocess)

def get_similarity_score(text1, text2):
  doc1 = nlp(text1)
  doc2 = nlp(text2)
  return doc1.similarity(doc2)

common_products = []
for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
  for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    similarity_score = get_similarity_score(row1["Name"], row2["Name"])
    if similarity_score > 0.9:
      common_products.append((row1["Brand"], row1["Name"], row1["Weight"], row2["Brand"], row2["Name"], row2["Weight"]))

for product in commmon_products:
  print(product)
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for this first cue. 
This code runs with a tokenization of "whole words". Could this be a limitation in a situation where the column values is maybe abbreviated, so maybe work on single characters? (I edit the example above).

As an ouput how could one go about having a final excell file where somehow one could link the two similar inputs found? (add them one row below the other or create a new column where you put the row number of the respective other retailer, ex link "12-20" means row 20 of the first is similar to row 20 of the second)

Comment: Concerning the abbreviated words, the best you can do is to create a dictionary mapping between the full words and the abbreviated ones. This is not a scalable solution, but as far as I can understand, is a possible solution. If you want to generate a final excel (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50008207/2371987) linking the two similar inputs, you can write to a new Excel file.